# Cassandra ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I have created the following schema to represent the association between a user and a set of threads ordered by their last message (which threads the user has read and which ones he has not):

```
CREATE TABLE table(user_id bigint, message_id bigint, thread_id bigint, read boolean, PRIMARY KEY(user_id, message_id)) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (message_id DESC);
CREATE INDEX ON table(read);
```

After inserting some values, I try to run this query to get the most recent read or unread threads for a user:

```
SELECT thread_id, message_id FROM table WHERE user_id = ? AND message_id < ? AND read = ? LIMIT ?
```

The query works if run via cqlsh. However, when run through the datastax client, on the client side we get a timeout exception and on the server side, the Cassandra log shows this exception:

```
ERROR [ReadStage:4190] 2013-12-10 13:18:03,579 CassandraDaemon.java (line 187) Exception in thread Thread[ReadStage:4190,5,main]
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy$DroppableRunnable.run(StorageProxy.java:1940)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at org.apache.cassandra.db.filter.SliceQueryFilter.start(SliceQueryFilter.java:261)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.index.composites.CompositesSearcher.makePrefix(CompositesSearcher.java:66)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.index.composites.CompositesSearcher.getIndexedIterator(CompositesSearcher.java:101)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.index.composites.CompositesSearcher.search(CompositesSearcher.java:53)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.index.SecondaryIndexManager.search(SecondaryIndexManager.java:537)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.search(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1669)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.PagedRangeCommand.executeLocally(PagedRangeCommand.java:109)
at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy$LocalRangeSliceRunnable.runMayThrow(StorageProxy.java:1423)
at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy$DroppableRunnable.run(StorageProxy.java:1936)
... 3 more
```

Does anyone know what the problem is? Thanks!

Comment: An unhandled `RuntimeException` on the server indicates a bug in the server, not a bug in your code.

Comment: @user3087110 You have a field in the select query that doesn't exist in the table declaration (the `network_id` field)

Comment: @LyubenTodorov you are right, it's just a mistype from cutting and copying code here.

Comment: @Raedwald true, but that does not explain why the query works via cqlsh and not via the datastax client.

Comment: Same problem here. A select in a table passed to cause this error. The query was working and stopped after i updated the driver (I'm using datastax java driver 2.0.0-beta2). Query works in cqlsh.

Answer (score 0):

This bug can now be tracked at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6470